# Copying xml declaration with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, declaration

How to copy xml declaration (version, encoding, standalone) with xsl?
I don't know what encoding, standalone will be in the input document, but in the output should be the same.

In `<xsl:output/>` information can't be copied from input.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to copy the XML declaration, because it does not exist in the parsed tree (it is only used by the parser to correctly parse the XML). And you would NOT want to copy it anyway, because it may render your result unusable - for example, when your output encoding is different from the original (as you probably noticed, the output encoding cannot be a dynamically calculated value).

Comment: XSLT itself doesn't have any representation of the XML input declaration in its data model so XSLT doesn't have the details. Depending on your programming environment, some DOM representations, for instance Microsoft .NET's DOM, with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldeclaration?view=net-7.0, stores such details, so if you run your XSLT with .NET code from a DOM input tree, you could read out the XML declaration properties and use them for serializing the transformation result as well. How you do that depends on the transformation/serialization API you use with .NET.

Comment: It seems the Java SAX API since Java 14 also reports the XML declaration https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#declaration(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String). That way on that platform, you could read out the input encoding and then make sure the output serialization uses the same encoding. But you need to do that mainly from Java code, that is not something XSLT provides.